# What's the most adapted programming language for Robotic and principally AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, programming-languages

I'm currency a Web programmer and I'm very passionate by robotics and specialty for Artificial Intelligence.

I have already make some C++ program for Microship and Arduino for little robots and other Lisp codes (example for labyrinth path search) but I think it's not really applicable for projects further.

I have read a lots for artificial neural network to create artificial mind, but it's very theoretical and I have no idea to reproduce that on code.

Someone have a idea to help me, a specific language, or just a C++ library ? 
If you have some links, articles, or other tutorials I take it.

Thank a lots !

Comment: "Best"-type questions are not particularly valuable for this format of discussion.  http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Okay, i'll change it

Answer (score 1):

Python has become increasingly popular in the computational sciences, but I'm not sure how widespread is its use in AI, machine learning, or robotics.

What I do know is that one popular choice is to use the open source [Robot Operating System (ROS)](http://www.ros.org) to interface code with hardware.  While it is not a programming language per se, it interfaces with lots of codes written generally in C++ and Python.

Answer (score 0):

I am a programmer for my schools robotics team. We use Robot C. Very similar to Java but with slight syntax differences. Specifically i work with Vex Robotics. One part of the code controls Autonomous (non user controlled) programming. Check it out!